# Weird DOF artifacts in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts, depth-of-field

Is there documentation somewhere on how exactly Cycles renders images with DOF?

I assumed it was using one of these two options:

1. It represents the camera as a zero-sized point in space. It spreads the effect rays have on the image after simulating their pinhole paths.
2. It represents the camera as a flat aperture in space. Rays that hit the aperture get assigned a pixel based on where they intersect the aperture and at what angle, using thin lens equations.

But I toyed around with it a bit and I think the answer may actually be neither? Here's a viewport screenshot of the setup I used:
[image]

I painted the default cube into some dim red, except for one bright green side. I oriented the camera so it looks straight into the cube, parallel to the green side. I moved it so it's just slightly offset to the right of the green side. A pinhole camera can't see the side, which is exactly what we see on a Cycles render without DOF (the renders are heavily cropped to only show the transition):
[image]

I enabled the DOF with f/1.4 and focused the camera at the front side. The result is exactly what you'd expect from option number 2: the camera can actually see the side because it's not just a zero-sized point in space.
[image]

But then I tried defocusing and I noticed weird things. Here's when the camera is focused too close:
[image]

And here's when it's focused too far:
[image]

I'm not exactly an optics expert, but these two images don't look right. Where does the gap come from when focusing too close, since the cube is a continuous object? And how did the green side shift to the right when focused too far?